# How to store credentials in sql configuration file as environment variables

Tags: mysql, docker, configuration-files, sqlconnection

I've got an SQL configuration file that's something like this:

```
[client]
database = dev
host = my-host.com
user = dev
password = super-secret-password
default-character-set = utf8
```

Is there any way I can swap out the plaintext host and password with some sort of environment variable, so I don't have to push it to GitHub directly? To deploy, I've been pushing to GitHub, making a docker image of the code pushed, pulling it onto an AWS server, and running it.

I'd rather not push the plaintext config file directly so I was wondering how to get around this.

Comment: What application framework is loading this?

Comment: A Django application

Answer (score 0):

You can use Github Secret to store sensitive data for your projects .
Read more about it from here ; [Creating encrypted secrets for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets)

Create Env Variable using Github Action:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Execute script
    env:
      PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SCRIPT_CREDENTIALS }}
    run: # your script to connect the database here .
```

for example to use a PHP script you can follow this method :

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = getenv("PASSWORD");

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

To make a change on a .cfg file you can also use githubaction like that :

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Edit your config file
    env:
      PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SCRIPT_CREDENTIALS }}
    run: echo "password = ${{ secrets.SCRIPT_CREDENTIALS }}" >> file.cfg
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using GitHub secrets for a few things but it's more of a syntax issue here, as in how to specify the secret/env variable to use in the config file

Comment: you can use github action to create env variable  after that you can use it like that , I'll make the change on my solution , thanks to check it .

Comment: hi, yes I have a github action environment variable, but I'm just not sure how to "plug it in" to the .cnf file - is there some sort of equivalent syntax for "getenv" in my local.cnf file?

Comment: I added a Github step to make a change inside your local.cfg file , I think it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Update on this for anyone using Django and having a similar issue, I was able to figure it out like this.

Before, my database connection file was set up like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "read_default_file": "local.cnf",
        },
    }
}
```

rather than doing this, it's easier to do something like:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        'NAME': 'dev',
        'USER': 'dev',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DEV_PASS'],
        'HOST': os.environ['DEV_HOST']
    }
}
```

so then you can specify your environment variables as usual.